# Jquery Tooltip works fine, then stops

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have added a jquery tooltip to a project at work. It's supposed to appear with an image inside on over of an element. Now, this works perfectly fine, but on one of the two pages that this tooltip appears, it'll randomly stop popping up on rollover unless refreshed.

Note that the other page does not exhibit this problem, and the code is the same for both, save the image itself. What I've noted through testing is the first page's tooltip stops working if you move the mouse over it fast enough that the tooltip starts to appear, then doesn't.

My question is: Is this a known bug? Is there a way to fix it? If so, what would it be?

For reference, my code:

```
function mouseRenewal() {
    $('#pinOver').tooltip({
        content: '<img src="../../Content/Images/renewalnotice.GIF" />'
    });
}
```

And the trigger element:

```
<%= Html.Label("Pin")%></div>
<%= Html.TextBox("Pin")%>&nbsp;
<span class="help">
     <a id="pinOver" title="" onclick="sampleRenewalOpen()" onmouseover="mouseRenewal()">What's this?</a>
</span>
```

Note: The onclick event of the element is for mobile browsers. It's so if you can't hover or if the hover breaks, you can open a popup window with the image in it.

EDIT: After further testing, I've concluded that it is not the speed of the mouseover. Repeated mouseovers in general recieve the issue, not even simply quicky ones. I am now attempting to use delay to try and make it work correctly and consistantly.

Comment: After looking at more pages and thinking a bit, would adding a delay to the tooltip closing possibly help? Or is that even possible? I'm thinking maybe on a fast mouseover, it's opening and closing so fast that it doesn't register as it closed, which could be causing the issue. I'm thinking either that, or maybe a delay on opening, if that's possible?

Comment: I've managed to fix it: Using `show: { delay: 75 }` in the tooltip call made it so mousing over it quickly wouldn't open the tooltip and close it quickly. This seems to be working, though I will be testing more before including that it is, 100%, fixed.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem. I would like to point out that you probably don't want to call `$('#pinOver').tooltip(...)` on every mouse over. Unless you are changing it each time you probably want to call that once on page load. The tooltip plugin will handle opening the tooltip with the mouseover.

Comment: @ioums I was unaware of this. This is my first time using tooltips. I'll keep that in mind in the future, and edit that in code. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing tooltip with each mouseover. Initialization is needed only once at the start.

```
$('#pinOver').tooltip({
    content: '<img src="../../Content/Images/renewalnotice.GIF" />'
});

<span class="help">
 <a id="pinOver" title="">  
    What's this?
</a>
</span>
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wuBzN/42/)